# Is intersection with the power of a polarization injective on the Chow Ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be an abelian variety of dimension g, and $x\in A$. Let $\theta$ be a polarization. Let $\theta_x$ denote its translate by $x$. Let $0\leq k\leq g$. If we have 
$$
\theta^{g-k}(\theta_x-\theta)^k=0
$$
in $\text{Ch}(A)$, where the exponents are intersection products, then is it true that $(\theta_x-\theta)^k=0$?

For context, a formula of Beauville gives us that
$$
\frac{\theta^{g-k}}{(g-k)!}(\theta_x-\theta)^k=\frac{\theta^g}{g!}*\gamma(x)^{*k}
$$
where $*$ is the Pontryagin product and $\gamma(x)=\sum_{v=1}^{g}\frac{1}{v}([0]-[x])^{*v}$. 
I want to show that if $\gamma(x)^{*k}=0$, then $(\theta_x-\theta)^k=0$. This comes up in the following preprint of Voisin in lemma 0.7: 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.07153.pdf

Comment: Which Chow group are you considering? If it is the usual one (cycles modulo rational equivalence), I suggest you consider the case of $g=1$.

Comment: Yes it is the usual one. For $g=1$, we have the two cases $k=0,1$. For $k=0$, the equation is just $\theta=0$, which doesn't happen because $\theta$ is ample. The case $k=1$ gives us the equation we want. I'm not sure how to generalize.

Comment: When $k=1$, you get $\theta_x-\theta=0$, which is not true in the Chow group. So, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I want to check: if $\theta^{g-k}(\theta_x-\theta)^k=0$, then $(\theta_x-\theta)^k=0$. So in the case $g=k=1$, the assumption doesn't occur, so the implication is vacuously true.

Comment: I am unclear what you are saying. If $g=k=1$, your equation says $\theta_x-\theta=0$, which is untrue.

Comment: So in the $g=k=1$ case, the statement: if $\theta^{g-k}(\theta_x-\theta)^k=0$ then $(\theta_x-\theta)^k=0$ translates to: if $\theta_x-\theta=0$ then $\theta_x-\theta=0$. This statement is true, despite the fact that $\theta_x-\theta=0$ can't happen.

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying. The intersection statement says this happens numerically, but numerical equivalence is not same as rational equivalence and in the Chow group this is not true.

Comment: What I’m saying basically has no mathematical content. I’m just saying that “False implies False” is a true statement, and that’s what the $g=k=1$ statement boils down to.

Answer (score 0):

> Let $A$ be an abelian variety of dimension g, and $x\in A$. Let $\theta$ be a polarization. Let $\theta_x$ denote its translate by $x$. Let $0\leq k\leq g$. If we have 
>   $$
> \theta^{g-k}(\theta_x-\theta)^k=0
> $$
>   in $\text{Ch}(A)$, where the exponents are intersection products, then is it true that $(\theta_x-\theta)^k=0$?

Your question has an affirmative answer although I could not locate it exactly, either in Bloch's paper or in Beauville's paper.

You can prove it directly by dominating your abelian variety $A$ by a product $C^g$---mapping to $A$ by the sum map. Then the two conditions are equivalent to the fact that $(\theta_x - \theta)^k$ pullback to $0$ in $\text{CH}_0(C^k)$, where $C^k$ maps to $A$ by the sum map.